# Reference error with module reveal pattern

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a sample code using js module reveal pattern

```
let appDashBoardFunctions = (()=> {   

    let openModal = ()=> {
        document.getElementById('addMemberPopup').classList.add('open');
    };

    let closeModal = ()=> {
        document.getElementById('addMemberPopup').classList.remove('open');
    };


    //reveal functions
    return {
        openModal: openModal,
        closeModal: closeModal
    }})();
```

i am able to use the function like this:

```
document.getElementById('openModalBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    appDashBoardFunctions.openModal()
});
```

but when using this as in a html button with onclick="appDashBoardFunctions.openModal()", i get a reference error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a *string* to `onclick` (whether in Javascript or in an HTML attribute), the interpreter only looks at the function name *on click*, essentially as an `eval` string - any variable inside an `onclick` string has to be *global* (assigned to `window`) or you'll get a `ReferenceError`. (Variables declared on the top level with `let` don't get assigned to `window`)

While you could fix it by assigning to `window.openModal` (or by using `var`), it would be better to simply assign the *function itself*, in Javascript, rather than a string in an HTML attribute:

```
someElement.onclick = appDashBoardFunctions.openModal;
```

If, inside the handler, you also need `this` to refer to the object that contains the function, then you'll have to tweak it a bit:

```
someElement.onclick = () => appDashBoardFunctions.openModal();
```

(otherwise, `this` inside the handler will refer to the element, rather than the module object)

Of course, as you've noted yourself, you can also use `addEventListener`, which works well too.

Comment: how do i use it like this <button id="addMemberPopup" onclick="appDashBoardFunctions.openModal();"></button> 

i get appDashNoardFunctions not defined error

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you *can* use `var` or assign to `window`, but you *shouldn't* - instead, attach the handler properly using Javascript rather than inline HTML attributes (which should be avoided just like `eval` - they're messy and hard to work with)